# Реализация интерфейсной команды с фоновой загрузкой данных wpf & mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Здравствуйте. Есть небольшая трудность с реализацией пользовательского меню. Использую wpf, prism и mvvm. Оболочка имеет 2 региона - main и menu. При загрузке модулей в menu (NavBarControl, DevExpress) регистрируются представления, которые представляют пункты меню (NavBarGroup). Каждый такой пункт содержит элементы (NavBarItem) к которым привязаны команды. При выборе пользователем NavBarItem запускается привязанная команда. Некоторые команды позволяют создавать новые сущности, но для этого им нужно получить данные с сервера. Когда грузятся эти данные приложение должно быть отзывчивым. Пока пришел к такому решению:

```
this.createAccount.Command = (ICommand)new DelegateCommand(this.ExecuteCreateAccount);

private void ExecuteCreateAccount()
    {
        AppEvent.OnShowNotificationEvent(UTNotificationType.ChangeMainLoaderStatus, "show", null);
        if (this.isCreateAccountProcessing)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.isCreateAccountProcessing = true;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.AccountListViewModel.LoadUsersCollection()).GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(this.ShowAccountEditor);
    }

    private void ShowAccountEditor()
    {
        AppEvent.OnShowNotificationEvent(UTNotificationType.ChangeMainLoaderStatus, null, null);
        this.isCreateAccountProcessing = false;

        if (this.createAccount.IsSelected)
        {
            this.AccountListViewModel.CreateNewItem();
        }
    }
```

Есть ли лучшая реализация этой задачи?
Когда обрабатывается фоновая операция показываю лоадер (AppEvent.OnShowNotificationEvent). Если пользователь выбрал другой пункт меню то команда должна быть отменена (не показываю окно редактора).